# WScript.CreateObject throwing "Could not create object" error in Windows Server 2016

Tags: vbscript, com, windows-server-2016, createobject

I am trying to create an object using `WScript.CreateObject("ProgID of com.dll")`.
      `CreateObject` method was working fine in Windows server 2008 and windows server 2012. But in windows server 2016, `CreateObject` method is not able to instantiate for a `com.dll` though it works for a normal DLL like `"Excel.Application"`.

Code:

```
Dim tool
Set tool = WScript.CreateObject("ProgID")
```

It's throwing the error message:

> WScript.CreateObject: Could not create object named "ProgID".

I have tried a few suggestions which I found in different sites to instantiate this like
`Set tool = CreateObject("ProgID")`

It throws the error message:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Out of memory: CreateObject

Is there any special execution instruction we need to take care of to avoid these errors? Has anyone has faced such errors?

Comment: Did you move to 64 bit Windows 2012 from a 32 bit Win 2008 system?